# Python Flask: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am learning Python Flask and I am working to a blog as personal project. I am using a combination of Flask and Sqlite but I am stuck because it seems that my system (I am using Windows 10) is not able to find the path to the database. This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime




 
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite: ////C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Blog_Project/blog.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Blogpost(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
    

@app.route('/post')
def post():
    return render_template('post.html')


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')


@app.route('/prova')
def prova():
    return render_template('prova.html')


@app.route('/add')
def add():
    return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
    title = request.form['title']
    subtitle = request.form['subtitle']
    author = request.form["author"]
    content = request.form['content']

    post = Blogpost(title=title, subtitle=subtitle, author=author, content=content, date_posted=datetime.now())

    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

But when I try to add a post in the corresponding webpage, I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'sqlite: ////C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Blog_Project/blog.db'
```

Actually the database should exist, since I see the file in my folder (the path is the one in the code)

[image]

Have you got any idea how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using double slashes:

```
sqlite: ////C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Blog_Project\\blog.db
```

or if you want to stay on windows, use the windows formation:

```
sqlite: ////C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Blog_Project\blog.db
```

you can learn more in this detailed answer: [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

For the convenience of `Linux` and `Windows` users, I have summarized **the solutions for this problem on `Windows` and `Linux`**:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# relative path on Linux: with three slashes
e = create_engine('sqlite:///relative/path/to/database.db')

# absolute path on Linux: with four slashes
e = create_engine('sqlite:////absolute/path/to/database.db')

# absolute path on Windows
e = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\database.db')
```

For detailed documents: [SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html)

Answer (score -1):

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db'

Comment: Just want to remind your guys, there are THREE forward slash (/) after sqlite rather than two

Comment: I see similar solution on github with a lot of votes. https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/322#issuecomment-349453719